# How do I create a working framework with dylib files in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, dylib

I have created a new cocoa framework in Xcode, removed all the libraries and files it includes at the beginning except the supporting files.

I have 2 files:

```
add.h

#ifndef add_add_h
#define add_add_h

void add(void);

#endif
```

and

```
add.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "add.h"

void add(void)
{
    printf("adfding");

}
```

in build phases I add add.c to compile sources and add.h to compile headers public. The project build without a problem but in the framework there is no dylib file and when I drag and drop the framework to another project it says that dylib file could not be found.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/add.framework/Versions/A/add 
  Referenced from: /Users/vjoukov/Desktop/Projects/test/build/Debug/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
  Reason: image not found
```

How can I make a simple framework and keep dylib files inside it ?

Answer (score 65):

I think you're misunderstanding the error message.

A `.framework` works as a dynamic library, but there won't be any Mach-O loadable object file with an actual `.dylib` filename extension inside the .framework folder.

There are a couple of reasons you might be getting that error message from `dyld`, the dynamic link library loader, at runtime. The first is that you forgot to copy the .frameworks into the built application bundle during the build process. While they can be copied to about any location inside the app bundle, the traditional place is in AppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/. If you haven't done so already, choose Project > New Build Phase > New Copy Files Build Phase. Change the Destination popup to Frameworks like in the image below.

[image]

You'll then drag the icon of the framework into the folder so that it's copied during the build process.

[image]

The second and more likely reason the framework can't be found at runtime is that you haven't specified any runpath search paths for your main executable. (This is needed, because, as we saw from your error message, your framework was built using the newer `@rpath/` style install name (`@rpath/add.framework/Versions/A/add`) rather than the older `@executable_path/` or `@loader_path/` styles).

Provided you copy the custom frameworks to the location mentioned above, you'd add a runpath search path entry of `@loader_path/../Frameworks`, like shown in the image below:

[image]

The following excerpt that explains how dynamic libraries are found at runtime is from the manpage of `dyld`:

> **DYNAMIC LIBRARY LOADING**
>
> Unlike many other operating  systems,  Darwin  does  not  locate
>   dependent  dynamic  libraries via their leaf file name. Instead the
>   full path to  each  dylib  is  used  (e.g. 
>   `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`).   But  there  are  times  when  a full
>   path is not appropriate; for instance, may want your binaries to be 
>   installable in anywhere on the disk.  To support that, there are three
>   `@xxx/` variables that can be used as a path prefix.   At  runtime `dyld`
>   substitutes a dynamically generated path for the `@xxx/` prefix.
>
> `@executable_path/`
>
> This variable is replaced with the path to  the  directory 
>   containing the main executable for the process.  This is useful for
>        loading dylibs/frameworks embedded in a .app directory.  If  the
>   main  executable  file is at `/some/path/My.app/Contents/MacOS/My`
>        and  a  framework  dylib  file  is   at
>   `/some/path/My.app/Contents/Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo`, 
>   then  the framework load path could be  encoded  as 
>   `@executable_path/../Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo`  and the
>   .app directory could
>        be moved around in the file system and `dyld` will still  be  able
>   to load the embedded framework.
>
> `@loader_path/`
>
> This  variable  is  replaced with the path to the directory
>   containing the mach-o binary which contains the load command  using
>        `@loader_path`.  Thus, in every binary, `@loader_path` resolves to a
>   different path, whereas `@executable_path` always resolves to  the
>        same  path. `@loader_path` is useful as the load path for a
>   framework/dylib embedded in a plug-in, if the final file system
>   location of the plugin-in unknown (so absolute paths cannot be used)
>        or if the plug-in is used by  multiple  applications  (so 
>   `@executable_path`  cannot  be used). If the plug-in mach-o file is at
>        `/some/path/Myfilter.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Myfilter` and a 
>   framework dylib file is at
>   `/some/path/Myfilter.plugin/Contents/Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo`,
>   then the framework load path
>        could   be   encoded   as 
>   `@loader_path/../Frameworks/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo` and the
>   `Myfilter.plugin` directory  could  be
>        moved  around  in the file system and `dyld` will still be able to
>   load the embedded framework.
>
> `@rpath/`
>
> Dyld maintains a current stack of  paths  called  the  run  path
>        list.   When  `@rpath`  is encountered it is substituted with each
>        path in the run path list until a loadable dylib if found.   The
>        run  path  stack is built from the `LC_RPATH` load commands in the
>        depencency chain that lead to the current dylib load.   You  can
>        add  an `LC_RPATH` load command to an image with the `-rpath` option
>        to `ld`(1).  You can even add a `LC_RPATH` load  command  path  that
>        starts  with  `@loader_path/`,  and it will push a path on the run
>        path stack that relative to the image containing  the  `LC_RPATH`.
>        The  use of `@rpath` is most useful when you have a complex
>   directory structure of programs and dylibs  which  can  be  installed
>        anywhere,  but  keep  their  relative  positions.  This scenario
>        could be implemented using `@loader_path`, but every client  of  a
>        dylib  could  need  a  different  load path because its relative
>        position in the file system is  different.  The  use  of  `@rpath`
>        introduces  a  level  of  indirection that simplies things.  You
>        pick a location in your directory structure as an anchor  point.
>        Each dylib then gets an install path that starts with `@rpath` and
>        is the path to the dylib relative to the anchor point. Each main
>        executable  is linked with `-rpath @loader_path/zzz`, where `zzz` is
>        the path from the executable to the anchor  point.   At  runtime
>        `dyld` sets it run path to be the anchor point, then each dylib is
>        found relative to the anchor point.

Comment: WOW! That's one heck of a complete answer, it also solved a problem I was having! Thanks!!

Comment: Very thorough and complete answer... Nice job!

Comment: Although this answer is very complete - it covers mainly the executable (App) relation to its framework (or other dylib). I need to build a single framework from several .dylibs (that should be embedded in that framework), and my executable barfs on my link errors on all the symbols in the embedded dylibs. I am trying to understand how to compose a framework from few dylibs - but no one seems to have written anything about this.

Comment: @NSGod, what would you do in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318465/setting-the-search-path-for-plug-in-dylib ? Thank You.